# How to assign a value array from json to particular table based on ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Im working on project which need to assign a value in array from json to particular ID on multiple table in  and .

As you see below the html that contains ID in title and odds. And you can see i was writing dead for this particular html therefore i need to retrieve from backend which the particular title and odds will be change based on the backend given value.

HTML

```
<tr><th class="GB1_0 name" id="t_B1_0" title="第一球 0"><input type="hidden" id="k_B1_0" value="BALL"><span class="b0">0</span></th>

<td class="GB1_0 odds" id="o_B1_0">9.93</td>
<td class="GB1_0 amount ha"><input name="B1_0" class="ba"></td>
</tr>
```

List of array with jSON ：
[image]

How do we do this ? Kindly advice Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
            <script>

            $( document ).ready(function() {                                      
                var jsonObj = {
                  B1_0 : 9.93,
                  B1_1 : 9.95,
                  B1_2 : 9.94

                };   

                $.each(jsonObj, function (index, value) {
                  console.log(index);
                  console.log(value);                      
                  $("#o_"+index).html(value);
                });


            });

        </script>
```

Comment: Hi Shah , exactly what i want , but can we make it to import for the title name too?

Comment: Almost similarly for title as well. Where exactly do you want title value? And what would that be? B1_0 and such?